# Input value change on submit

Tags: html, asp-classic

I've got the following code for the the top search bar to allow empty values:

```
if(SearchQuery = "" or SearchQuery = "e.g.") then
SearchQuery = ""
```

The problem is the section headings show the following whether the input is empty or has 'e.g.':

Any ideas how to fix this?

There is also a space missing between e.g. for certain pages 2, but it's not like that in the code:

```
<input type="text" name="Q" value="e.g." onclick="if (this.defaultValue == this.value) { this.value = ''; }">
```

Basically we need the placeholder text, 'e.g.', but not to submit that as a value.

Comment: When do you want it to be displayed then?

Comment: clarify your question little more clear.

Comment: Thought people would have heard of `ADODB.Command` by now, instead of relying on sanitation user defined functions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a space in your code between e.g. and Shops

```
if(SearchQuery = "" or SearchQuery = "e.g.Shops")
```

You are checking for 'e.g.Shops': and not 'e.g.[SPACE]Shops':

I might make a suggestion:

```
 SearchQuery=trim(SearchQuery)
 if (SearchQuery = "" or lcase(SearchQuery) = "e.g. shops") then SearchQuery = ""
```

That way if someone enters in " " or "" it is the same and you don't have to worry about upper or lower case on the second part of the OR

Comment: I can't tell without seeing more of your code but if you don't need the variable later on just replace the spaces and check for it.
eg. SearchQuery=trim(replace(SearchQuery," ","")) and then check for lcase(SearchQuery) = "e.g.shops"

Comment: There is your problem you are using the querystring, take a look at the querystring value for Q. It contains no spaces (not that I recommend spaces in the URL)

Comment: I can see your updates, but now I don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: Querystring and form data are different, you are using the querystring data